# Remove required attribute google recapture v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, recaptcha

I have a Google recapture on a form which unfortunately is not model binded and so model validation does not work.  I use form collection to deal with form submitted values in the controller.  I am able to prevent form submission if captcha is not checked in the controller and redirect back to form but because is not model binded all values are cleared which is a pain to users.This calls for me to validate the Google captcha using a JavaScript  on the client side which am not very good at.

On the form

```
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="CaptchaDeText"></label>
    <div style="position:relative">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxx"></div>
    <input id='recaptcha_check_empty' required tabindex='-1',style='width:50px; 
 height:0; opacity:0;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;bottom:0;'>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Javascipt function called on submit

```
function isCaptchaChecked() {
    var capcha = false;
    if (grecaptcha && grecaptcha.getResponse().length !== 0) {
    $('#recaptcha_check_empty').find('.control-group').removeClass('error');
        capcha = true;
        return true;
    };
    if (!capcha) {
        $('#modalMessage').find('#modalBody').html(noCaptchaMessage);
        $('#modalMessage').modal('show');
        $('#recaptcha_check_empty').find('.control-group').addClass('error');

    };

    return false;
}
```

My problem is how to remove the required  attribute when the user becomes validated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#recaptcha_check_empty').removeAttr('required');​​​​​
```